# Bug em "Mais comunidades do Stack Exchange"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Não sei se erro já foi reportado, mas como o notei decidi postar aqui.

Na aba das comunidades, em "Mais comunidades do Stack Exchange", todos elas estão com creio que um erro de tradução.
Por exemplo:

> Academia: "Para" academics and those enrolled in higher education.

[image: Erro de tradução]

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas acredito que seja algo bem complicado (até mesmo impossível), pois estas descrições são das próprias comunidades, como pode ser visto [aqui](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic). Só o *"Para"* que parece ser uma "variável" de tradução do *SOpt*.

Comment: Acho que o certo seria des-traduzir o "Para", e deixar "For" mesmo. São comunidades em inglês, que fique a descrição inteira em inglês.

Comment: @Math foi o que eu pensei que fosse o mais fácil(correto) de fazer, até porque como você disse são comunidades em inglês.

Comment: Acho que você deveria abrir essa mesma questão no MetaSE e pedir para traduzirem o "For" da descrição do SOPT para "Para". [**Olhas só como tá lá.**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L9kie.png) :P

Comment: Vou fazer isso @Math!

Comment: Eu falei mais na brincadeira, mas se estiver com disposição siga em frente, é uma causa justa. Depois coloca o link aqui para pessoal daqui poder votar e acompanhar :)

Comment: Não custa nada ajudar a melhorar o site que me ajuda tanto ;)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291265/translation-error-in-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-community aqui está @Math, inclusive usei seu print screen! haha

Comment: Mas no SOEN ocorre o mesmo erro...

Comment: Perdão se coloquei no lugar errado ou fiz confusão ainda não entendo muito bem dessas coisas da comunidade. :p

Comment: Sua pergunta fez sucesso lá hein? :)

Comment: Deu o que discutir hahaha